# Add click event to child by selecting parent with dynamically added class

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, click, addclass

I've been trying to get Twitter's Bootstrap dropdown parent links to function as normal anchor tags on the second click to allow the user to open the dropdown on mobile with the first tap and then on the second, navigate to the parent link's href. To achieve this I noticed that when the dropdown has been clicked once, it automatically adds a class of open to the dropdown parent li. However, when I try to select this with jQuery, find its child anchor with a class of dropdown-toggle and add a click event to this anchor, nothing happens. My html is as follows:

```
<li class="dropdown open">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle visible-md visible-lg visible-xl">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <a href="http://google.com" class="dropdown-toggle visible-sm visible-xs" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And my jQuery is this (it's just a console.log statement for now as a test):

```
$('li.dropdown.open').find('a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function() {
console.log('works');
});
```

Also, just fyi, the reason that there are two dropdown-toggle links is because one shows on desktop and allows the user to hover to show the dropdown and the other acts as the standard bootstrap dropdown that's triggered on click.

Comment: is there a reason you dont use the bootstrap event itself? reference:  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Comment: try putting the above jquery code inside callback for following event :  $('#myDropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
  // do something…
})

Comment: Thanks guys I hadn't seen that yet (this is the first site I'm using Bootstrap on). Using on('hide.bs.dropdown') works perfectly.